# Help with component identification

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, components, surface-mount

The component (IC206) is on the mainboard BN94-13095E of a Samsung TV model UN43J5290AG.

[image]

Comment: It is a 4.7 uH SMD inductor.

Comment: +1 for the tag choices.

Comment: Can you clarify which component you want to identify? jusaca has already identified ``L203`` but from the question wasn't sure if you wanted to identify ``IC206``.

Comment: If you want to know what IC206 is: Can you confirm that the text on the IC is "TtACI"? 'It is hard to see with the image quality.

Comment: Sorry about this.. is The IC206, “TtACI” or “TtAC1” i can’t be sure..

Comment: From the markings, it could be a [Silergy](https://www.silergy.com/) part. They sometimes use mixed upper and lower case, like [here](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/DC-DC-Converters_Silergy-Corp-SY8401ABC_C125906.html). If it's indeed made by Silergy then there doesn't seem to be a public datasheet available.